# Stop wifi hotspots changing page history

Tags: wireless-networking, browser, browser-tabs

Everytime you connect to a public wifi hotspot it will force whatever tab you load to show their login screen, so you can login to their system, which fine, but this can be infuriating when you open a browser with a number of tabs after connecting to one of these hotspots as they tend to do a hard redirect on each tab rather than just forward you on to their login page, which results in the history of the tabs you had intended to load being lost.

Is there a way to prevent these pages loading up on public wifi's so you can choose which browser to use to login to their network? I guess it's some kind of tab hijacking blocker.